# Starting User script in Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Is it possible to run a user script before the page and DOM loads?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There is not much you can do (to the document) before DOM loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if the [user script runs on google chrome](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts) atm. Greasemonkey may support this too someday:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name My script
// @description It's really neat
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==
```

Answer (score 1):

As Erik Vold said, Greasemonkey cannot do this unless the browser is Chrome.

But, if this functionality is needed on any other browser, you can [write an extension](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/byofirefoxpdf1/).